# Track key presses in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, macos

I'm looking for a simple way to run something on a unix machine and track when a specific key is pressed. So when someone hits a key on their keyboard, it fires some sort of event.

I am not a c/c++ dev so if someone could point me in the right direction. Running OSX

Comment: Do you want to intercept keys intended for *your* application, or keys intended for *another* application?

Comment: Intercept keys when you are in focus anywhere in the OS. To give some more detail, I'm looking to capture a cetain keypress, and then listen for that event with Nodejs. I can do the node part myself but dont have much experience with C/C++ Extensions..

Comment: The solution to this would be specific to OSX. You might want to re-tag your question.

Comment: This *should* be impossible (by design) unless you're running as root.  If you are running as root, you best bet would probably be looking for event hooks in X windows, followed by checking the kernel source code for however X gets keypresses.

Comment: @David X Mac OS X (mentioned in the question) does not use X but one can do this using Accessibility if the user explicitly allows this. No need to be root. Of course you can always write a kext if you don't want the user to explicitly allow this. Yep, it is relatively easy to write a keylogger for Mac OS X.

Comment: If you're not a C or C++ developer, why do you want to write this in C or C++?

Answer (score 1):

Any GUI toolkit will provide an event loop that deals with keyboard and other events.

Don't build one yourself if you aren't a pro.